# Read files in Directory and take diff

Tags: linux, bash, diff

I have two directories named comp1 and comp2 and both have files named file1 and file2.

I need a bash script which read file1 from both the directories and take diff of each file and redirect to some other file. For example.

diff comp1/file1 comp2/file1 > file1.diff

Comment: `diff -Nru comp1 comp2`, oh and `man diff`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in comp1/* ; do
  diff "comp1/$f" "comp2/$f" > "$f.diff"
done
```

This script assumes you have files of the same name in both directories.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, that what I need. What if we need this recursively?  for example further in comp1 directory there is another directory?

Comment: It depends on where you want to have the file with the output of diff.
If you want it in one file, just use `diff -Nru` as proposed by @dawud.
If you want separate files, just separate the output at '^---' with csplit.

Comment: Don't iterate over the output of `ls`. Just use a glob. And quote your variables.

Comment: I have fixed the code in the answer.